# Using identityDbContext and identity user with strongly-typed ids

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add identityDbContext to my application where I have strongly typed id as primary key for user, as far as my concern, IdentityDbContext must get object which is IdentityUser or child of it.
My question is how to add IdentityDbContext with IdentityUser which has strongly typed id.

```
public class InstagramDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, IdentityRole<Guid>, UserId>
{
   // some code
}
```

[InstagramDbContext has this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyvKL.png)

```
public record UserId(Guid Value);

public class User : IdentityUser<UserId>
{
    public UserId UserId { get; set; } = null!;
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the definition of `IdentityDbContext` you'll see something like this.

```
public class IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey> : IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, IdentityUserClaim<TKey>, IdentityUserRole<TKey>, IdentityUserLogin<TKey>, IdentityRoleClaim<TKey>, IdentityUserToken<TKey>>
        where TUser : IdentityUser<TKey>
        where TRole : IdentityRole<TKey>
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
```

You have specified `TKey` as `UserId` in your case. Therefore you can't do `IdentityRole<Guid>`. Because `TRole` must be `IdentityRole<TKey>`. You can see the constraint in `IdentityDbContext` definition.

In order to fix this, change the type of `IdentityRole` to `UserId` in your case. `IdentityRole<UserId>`

```
public class InstagramDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, IdentityRole<UserId>, UserId>
{
   // some code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From your question, there is not a lot to go on, what's Instagram.Domain.Users.UserId ?

But you could try using an explicit (or implicit) operator

```
using System;

public readonly struct Digit
{
    private readonly byte digit;

    public Digit(byte digit)
    {
        if (digit > 9)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(digit), "Digit cannot be greater than nine.");
        }
        this.digit = digit;
    }

    public static implicit operator byte(Digit d) => d.digit;
    public static explicit operator Digit(byte b) => new Digit(b);

    public override string ToString() => $"{digit}";
}

public static class UserDefinedConversions
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var d = new Digit(7);

        byte number = d;
        Console.WriteLine(number);  // output: 7

        Digit digit = (Digit)number;
        Console.WriteLine(digit);  // output: 7
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators